# Help! I'm Taking Differential Calculus Next Semester

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm taking a differential calculus class next semester, but I didn't learn anything in pre-calculus in my 11th grade. What do I need to know before I start? What's the prerequisite? And why do I keep getting results for differential equations when I search for differential calculus? Are they the same thing?

Comment: Differential equations are a major application of differential calculus. Or rather, they're a major topic of interest especially for applied mathematicians and to even state them, never mind solve them, one needs differential calculus. Pre-reqs should be detailed by your course teacher. There are a gazillion online (especially YouTube) resources too. 3blue1brown's 'essence of calculus' is good for new students but is by no means the only solution if you need to play catch-up

Comment: Talk to the person who will be teaching the course. That's the person in the best position to help you.

Comment: Is "differential calculus" an alternative name for people who do not like the classical "infinitesimal calculus"? Then the initial topics are real numbers, sequences, limits, series, continuous functions, derivatives and (Riemann) integrals. In-between the pocket calculator functions, exponentials, logarithm, trigonometric functions.

Comment: I don't know who the professor will be for my differential calculus class next semester. My university doesn't release the professor names in advance, so I won't know until the first day of class. I want to study in advance so that I won't be behind when the class starts.

Comment: There should be a module description available, if not for the current year then for the last. The introductory courses are usually standardized in their content.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, I can't to get my hands on the syllabus since it is not available publicly, it is only posted on the student who is currently enrolled in that course. But I reached out to someone who is currenty in that course. I really appreciate your help everyone!!

Comment: Khan Academy's [Get Ready for AP Calculus](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/get-ready-for-ap-calc) course might be a good place to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it's been more than a week but I still like to answer this for anyone who would come looking for this answer.

But first, let me tell OP that this is not the right platform to ask these questions. Here mathematical problems are answered. Quora and appropriate subreddits are better platforms.

---

So a few years back I was in the same shoes. COVID-19 led me to very bad decisions when I was in 11th grade - I ended up skipping the whole year. But in 12th grade, I needed to study calculus so after a lot of messing around, in my opinion, these are the best steps to get ready for Calculus:

**Step 1:** Learn about Trigonometry. Any book with introductions to Trig would suffice. The main objective is to get a clear understanding of Trig functions in Unit circle representation.

*Resource a:* This video helped me at the start. [Trigonometry fundamentals | Lockdown math by 3Blue1Brown](https://www.youtube.com/live/yBw67Fb31Cs?si=0R_0S0EyyxUF8p7w)

*Resource b:* Actually the whole series would be good to brush up on fundamentals: [Lockdown Math by 3Blue1Brown](https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLZHQObOWTQDP5CVelJJ1bNDouqrAhVPev&si=SC1qATXVVJdp-uok)

Then I would suggest you try to understand why the lines in the following picture equal to defination of Trig functions:

[image: trig functions]

But do note $\tan \& \cot$ can be expressed by taking the $\perp$ or tangent at $(1,0)$

[image: Another visual of tan]

*Resource c:* This animation can help you understand the graphs of Trig functions: [Animation of Trig](https://www.geogebra.org/m/cNEtsbvC)

**Step 2:** After understanding Trig functions start practising derivation of trig identities. Always remember while remembering formulas make solving fast but in the real world, if you don't know the intuition behind them you would most likely fail to see the pattern.

*Resource d:* Some common identities (I carry this cheat sheet even now)

[image: Indenties]

**Step 3:** After you're comfortable with Trig, start solving any textbook questions. While this seems like it will take too much, you would be able to complete it in 2 weeks.

*Resource e:* My goto book is: Plane Trigonometry Part 1 by SL Loney.

**Step 4:** Now is the time you should be introduced to calculus. I'm gonna give a series, free on YT, that explains every topic in the First year of Calculus using 100% Animation. This series has 4 Seasons but I would recommend only the first 2 as the rest are kind of off-topic and only continue if you're interested.

*Resource f:* https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLZHQObOWTQDPD3MizzM2xVFitgF8hE_ab&si=oombHBFS9hBtAqLJ

**Step 5:** Next I would recommend just solving PreCalc Algebra.

*Resource g:* My goto book is Higher Algebra by Hall & Knight

**Step 6:** In the final step, start solving the starting chapters of your curriculum to get the upper hand in your lecture.

Comment: No mention of Analytic Geometry? I've seen Calculus courses that don't require any Trigonometry, but I can't imagine an intro Calculus course that doesn't rely heavily on Analytic Geometry.

Comment: Analytic geometry is indeed a very useful field. And it’s included. The book Plane Trigonometry and Higher Algebra both cover Analytic geometry.

Comment: Thanks man, I reallly appreciate the effort you put up here, will definitely use this. Thank you very much!